# Prove that for $f,g\in\mathbb{N}[x]$ and $K(f)=\gcd(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$, $K(fg)=K(f)K(g)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{a_nx^n}$ with $a_n\in\mathbb{N}$ and define $K(f)=\gcd(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$. How would I go about proving that $K(fg)=K(f)K(g)$? The only way I can think of doing this problem is by multilying out $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and finding $K(fg)$ manually. Is there any simpler way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Gauss' Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_(polynomial)). It reduces to prove that if $K(f) = K(g) = 1$, then $K(f g) = 1$. I just taught this yesterday, and the speediest way, if you have covered the material, is to argue by contradiction, suppose a prime $p$ divides all coefficients of $f g$, reduce modulo $p$, and obtain a contradiction in the ring of polynomials with coefficients in the integers modulo $p$.

**PS** You probably want your polynomials to have integer coefficients.